# How to use llvm elementwise atomic intrinsics?

Tags: llvm, atomic, intrinsics, llvm-ir

LLVM has elementwise atomic intrinsics [see here](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-memcpy-element-unordered-atomic-intrinsic). However when I try to use them, with IR like the following:

```
 call void @llvm.memcpy.element.unordered.atomic.p0i8.p0i8.i32(i8* align 4 %P, i8* align 4 %Q, i32 4, i32 1)
```

then when I try to link, I get the error:

```
 undefined reference to `__llvm_memcpy_element_unordered_atomic_1'
```

is there a special library I need to link to or something?

Also, this happens with code generated using the `IRBuilder::CreateElementUnorderedAtomicMemCpy` method.

Comment: I haven't heard of these LLVM-IR intrinsics, but possibly `-latomic`?  If you compile with optimization enabled, does it inline?  With a fixed len of 4 x 1-byte elements, this should definitely inline to a single 4-byte load/store for any 32 or 64-bit target.  If it compiled to asm that makes an actual function call, it's not very useful at this point except maybe for large copies.

Comment: Interesting... with `-O1` it does inline it for this example. However, this is just an example, and the real use case is a compiler, which may or may not use optimization options, and the length may be larger than 4 (or dynamic)

Comment: Ok, that's fine then.  My point was that if it didn't inline at `-O3` for this case, it would be not worth using with current LLVM.  (And I wondered if maybe it wasn't recognized at all, and just treated like an unknown external function name.  But on second look, the name doesn't exactly match so clearly LLVM understood it as an intrinsic.)

Comment: Did you try `find -type f -exec nm {} +`  (or `nm --dynamic`) in a directory of LLVM's libraries, to see if the symbol name appears in any shared / static libraries?

Comment: I didn't find anything. I wonder if the user is expected to provide an implmentation for these functions. But if so, that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: Maybe worth searching in the LLVM git repo to see if there's (asm) source for a non-inline version of it anywhere.  Hmm, nope, https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/search?q=__llvm_memcpy_element_unordered_atomic_1&unscoped_q=__llvm_memcpy_element_unordered_atomic_1 just shows references to it, or a testcase that's supposed to emit a call to it.

Comment: Searching on `memcpy element unordered`  with spaces finds places that emit calls to it, but still no definition.  https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/search?q=memcpy+element+unordered&unscoped_q=memcpy+element+unordered